# ListBox Scroll Turns Black / Glitches On Vertical Scroll - Redraw Issue?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, system.drawing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0xY5.jpg

Video example in link above. (Short, 30 seconds)

listBox works fine until scrolling is needed.
When scrolling, listBox changes background, turns black, glitches out.
Have attempted OwnerDrawFixed mode but then listBox shows empty.
Has anyone else seen this before?

After Scroll:

[image]

After drag select/click:

[image]

Code Snippets:
[Form1 Designer.vb]

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(Form1))
        Me.Timer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
        Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.PictureBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.ListBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ListBox()
        Me.OpenFileDialog1 = New System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog()
        Me.PictureBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.PictureBox3 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.PictureBox4 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.LinkLabel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel()
        Me.NotifyIcon1 = New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(Me.components)
        Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox3, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox4, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Timer1
        '
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
        Me.Timer1.Interval = 200
        '
        'TextBox1
        '
        Me.TextBox1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 15.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 77)
        Me.TextBox1.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6, 5, 6, 5)
        Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
        Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(293, 31)
        Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(153, 118)
        Me.Button1.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6, 5, 6, 5)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(192, 35)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'PictureBox1
        '
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("PictureBox1.Image"), System.Drawing.Image)
        Me.PictureBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.PictureBox1.Name = "PictureBox1"
        Me.PictureBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(44, 44)
        Me.PictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        Me.PictureBox1.TabIndex = 2
        Me.PictureBox1.TabStop = False
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 15.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(62, 23)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(283, 23)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 3
        Me.Label1.Text = "My App"
        '
        'ListBox1
        '
        Me.ListBox1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.ListBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
        Me.ListBox1.ItemHeight = 16
        Me.ListBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 161)
        Me.ListBox1.Name = "ListBox1"
        Me.ListBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(333, 180)
        Me.ListBox1.TabIndex = 4
        '
        'OpenFileDialog1
        '
        Me.OpenFileDialog1.AddExtension = False
        Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "OpenFileDialog1"
        Me.OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        Me.OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        Me.OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
        '
        'PictureBox2
        '
        Me.PictureBox2.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("PictureBox2.Image"), System.Drawing.Image)
        Me.PictureBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(314, 77)
        Me.PictureBox2.Name = "PictureBox2"
        Me.PictureBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 31)
        Me.PictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        Me.PictureBox2.TabIndex = 5
        Me.PictureBox2.TabStop = False
        '
        'PictureBox3
        '
        Me.PictureBox3.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("PictureBox3.Image"), System.Drawing.Image)
        Me.PictureBox3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 118)
        Me.PictureBox3.Name = "PictureBox3"
        Me.PictureBox3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 31)
        Me.PictureBox3.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        Me.PictureBox3.TabIndex = 6
        Me.PictureBox3.TabStop = False
        '
        'PictureBox4
        '
        Me.PictureBox4.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("PictureBox4.Image"), System.Drawing.Image)
        Me.PictureBox4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(314, 355)
        Me.PictureBox4.Name = "PictureBox4"
        Me.PictureBox4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 31)
        Me.PictureBox4.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        Me.PictureBox4.TabIndex = 7
        Me.PictureBox4.TabStop = False
        '
        'LinkLabel1
        '
        Me.LinkLabel1.AutoSize = True
        Me.LinkLabel1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.LinkLabel1.LinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        Me.LinkLabel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 373)
        Me.LinkLabel1.Name = "LinkLabel1"
        Me.LinkLabel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(126, 15)
        Me.LinkLabel1.TabIndex = 8
        Me.LinkLabel1.TabStop = True
        Me.LinkLabel1.Text = "label"
        Me.LinkLabel1.VisitedLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        '
        'NotifyIcon1
        '
        Me.NotifyIcon1.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("NotifyIcon1.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
        Me.NotifyIcon1.Text = "My App"
        Me.NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        '
        'Button2
        '
        Me.Button2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(153, 355)
        Me.Button2.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6, 5, 6, 5)
        Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
        Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(152, 31)
        Me.Button2.TabIndex = 9
        Me.Button2.Text = "Button"
        Me.Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(13.0!, 23.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(357, 397)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.LinkLabel1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox4)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox3)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.ListBox1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
        Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 15.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
        Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        Me.Text = "My App"
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox3, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox4, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents Timer1 As Timer
    Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox1 As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As Label
    Friend WithEvents ListBox1 As ListBox
    Friend WithEvents OpenFileDialog1 As OpenFileDialog
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox2 As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox3 As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox4 As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents LinkLabel1 As LinkLabel
    Friend WithEvents NotifyIcon1 As NotifyIcon
    Friend WithEvents Button2 As Button
End Class
```

[Form1.vb]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            If System.IO.File.Exists("myfile.txt") Then
                Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt")
                ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
            End If
        End Sub
```

Example of 'myfile.txt' contents:

```
iexplore1
iexplore2
iexplore3
iexplore4
... [And so on]
```

Comment: We should NEVER have to tell you this: SHOW US THE CODE.

Comment: So there was no owner-drawing initially? Are you handling any events of that control? If you add another `ListBox` to the same form or a different form, does it behave the same way?

Comment: BTW, if you configure the `ListBox` to be owner-drawn then you (the owner) have to draw the items, which means handling the `DrawItem` event and drawing the current item. That's not something that you should ever have to do to fix an issue though. You do it if and only if you want the items drawn in a way other than the default.

Comment: Why did you tag the question with `System.Drawing`? Where's the drawing part? Do you have some sort of loop somewhere? Are you using `Control.CreateGraphics()` somewhere?

Comment: Probably this is a custom ListBox and you `SetStyle(...)` in the constructor to takeover the painting of the control _(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint/ControlStyles.UserPaint)_? If so, comment the `SetStyle` code, set `DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`, and override the `OnDrawItem` method to draw the items as mentioned.

Comment: Search the project for `Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem`.  If you find this method, then any syntax inside is what's changing colors.   Also, set `DrawMode = Normal` and the colors will remain default.

Comment: So you aren't using a custom ListBox. What do you have in the `Timer1.Tick` event? Show us the `Form1.vb` file.